# Keep nodes separate in Graphviz graph

Tags: graphviz

I have a simple graphviz graph with two entities who work for different organisations:

```
digraph G {
    worksFor [color=".7 .3 1.0"];
    John -> worksFor -> "Carpenters Ltd.";
    Lucy -> worksFor -> "Builders Ltd.";
}
```

As you can see in the screenshot, there is no way to tell who works at which company:
[image: graphviz graph]

How can I tell Graphviz to keep the 'worksFor' separate from each other?

Comment: Can you share what the outcome should be, even taking a photo of a scribble? Without that, i don't think an answer is possible, even though @Marcin had a good first idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far I understand you want to express type of relation between persons and their empolyers. I think that "works for" should be added as edge label.

```
digraph G {
    John -> "Carpenters Ltd." [ label="works for" ];
    Lucy -> "Builders Ltd." [ label="works for" ];
}
```

You can check the result on http://graphviz.it/#/rVaZeunG.

If you want to keep "works for" as node you can use two nodes with the same label.

```
digraph G {
    rel1, rel2 [ label="works for" ];
    John -> rel1 ->"Carpenters Ltd.";
    Lucy -> rel2 -> "Builders Ltd.";
}
```

Result of the second source you can find on http://graphviz.it/#/fyBPFHxh/1